# "Makes them difficult to simulate" vs "makes it difficult to simulate them"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, pronouns, syntactic-analysis, dummy-it

Which statement is correct?

> 1. The complexity of these systems makes them difficult to simulate on computers.
> 2. The complexity of these systems makes it difficult to simulate them on computers.

Comment: I agree with Noah. The issue is what are you trying to convey? Are the simulations complete? Are they hard to get exactly correct?  Are they time-consuming to run. Are they easier to simulate on something else? Will they be hard to construct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use 2, although 1 is not completely off if you change it to 
*The complexity of these systems makes them difficult to be simulated on computers.*

Comment: Your rewrite sounds far worse than the original (which was quite acceptable). This is endorsed by these Ngrams: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are+difficult+to+simulate%2Care+difficult+to+be+simulated&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=

Comment: There is a difference between "are different to simulate" and "makes them different to simulate". http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=makes+them+difficult+to+simulate%2Cmakes+them+difficult+to+be+simulated&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=

Answer (score 0):

Well, both are correct but mean different things. In the first one *them* refers to the *systems*. The second one is a little ambiguous but I'd guess that by *it* you are generally referring to the process of simulation.

Answer (score 0):

**Both are correct and there is no difference in meaning.**

The variant that should easily be seen to be totally acceptable is:

> 3-  It is difficult to simulate these systems on computers because
>   they (the systems) are so complex.

Here, 'dummy it' (not referring to anything other than the situation in general - ie there is no antecedent to which 'it' here corresponds) is used. (2) is a slight variation on this, and stylishly preferable (the possible ambiguity doesn't arise).

(1) is also a perfectly acceptable construction (20.7 million Google hits for "makes them difficult to") although it probably sounds incongruous for two reasons:

(a) it perhaps sounds odd for complexities to be said to 'make' something (here, 'is the reason that they are' sounds less odd than 'makes them')

(b) it perhaps sounds odd for something to be said to 'be made difficult to...' (here, 'is the reason that they are not easily simulated on computers' sounds less odd than 'makes them difficult to simulate on computers'.

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are understandable, but not completely clear. How about this unambiguous rewrite:

> The complexity of these systems makes simulating them on computers
>   difficult.